How do I check a player's inventory for specific items?
I'm trying to test someone's inventory for specific blocks so that I can take said blocks out one at a time and pay them a specified amount of money for those blocks. This is for a shop system I'm creating in a mining game (yes, it's just like prison on servers).
I'm practically at square one, as nothing has worked yet. Due to my lack of knowledge (and the fact you can't scroll the commands on Bedrock), I can't figure out which command will work for this.
I have tried to use /testfor, but all of the actions it tells you will work have nothing to do with inventory testing.

Welcome to Arqade! On Minecraft commands questions, please see our guide on what to do before asking a Minecraft commands question, especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far”, and edit in the requested information to your post.

I'm happy you found your solution! Could you instead please post the edit you made as an answer below? We love it when people find answers to their own questions!

I was under the assumption i culdent anser till i had standing like every thing else

Couldn't you just use /clear @p iron 64? Or is that just Java Edition?

This is how I got it to work:
/testfor @p [hasitem = {item=sand}]  

